# Stopping a form from reloading the page

Tags: javascript, html

I am developing a web application over an APACHE 2 web server. When I execute my dropbox.html file, it produces a drop down menu created using PHP of all of the files in my htdocs directory. This is where my files will be for processing. When a file is selected, a javascript function is called and this goes through a long process of analyzing the file with a perl script and so forth. The end game is that I want a graph to be generated and appear when the processing is done. I had the graph working before I had the drop down menu, I simply had a button that called this same JS function and it worked fine on a single hard coded file. Here is my problem: Now that I have the drop box working, I can see that the graph pops up [correctly] but it only does so for a second before the whole page resets back to the starting form [which would be showing the first file in the drop down menu]. How can I stop this from resetting? i.e. when I click on something from the drop down menu, it should stay on that file until I change it. I want my graph to stay up until the user chooses another file to process.

Here are excerpts from my dropbox.html file. First, my code for the drop box. I am leaving out the standard html code and just showing you the meat that you need to.

```
<!--The following is php code which gets the files in the current directory and 
populates a drop down menu with those files, it calls the openfilex method-->

<form name="filex" method="get" action="" onsubmit="openfilex()">
<select name="select">
<?php
$files = array_map("htmlspecialchars", scandir("."));
foreach ($files as $file)
    echo "<option value='$file'>$file</option>";
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Choose File">
</form>
```

Next the JS function it calls. You can see that my JS function calls a perl script, passing the filename as a parameter, and returns data from the perl script which is being parsed [all the pops, pushes]. When you start seeing HitCntGraph, these are calls to a javascript library I have plot.js which are methods for creating and drawing a graph. There should be no problems there as it worked before.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//The following is the function associated with the event: file selected
function openfilex(){

var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    var str, wordCnt, word;
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) { // Get the results of the perl script
        // Get the complete string
        str = xmlhttp.responseText;
        str = str.substring(24);
        //alert(str);

        // Split it into the numberical results adding the keywords at the end as a long string
        wordCnt = str.split("-");
        //get the big string at the end
        word = wordCnt.pop();
        // Now split apart this big word into an array of the key words
        word = word.split(",");
        //we must pop the last element off since the string ended in an ',' which means there
        //is an extra element on this array [empty]
        word.pop();

        //word is now an array whose elements are each a keyword
        //alert(word);
        //wordCnt is now an array whose elements are each a keyword count
        //alert(wordCnt);

        var length = wordCnt[0]; //get the numer of xaxis ticks
        for(var i=0; i < length; i++) { //initialize the x-axis array 
            wordCnt[i] = wordCnt[i+1]; 
        } 

        //this will leave an extra element on the end [we essentially shrunk our array by one] so we pop this off.
        wordCnt.pop();

        // Create the graph [see the library]
        HitCntGraph = new MakeDraw();
        HitCntGraph.grid=1;
        HitCntGraph.enumerateP = 0;
        HitCntGraph.id="HitCntGraphCanvas";

        HitCntGraph.data = wordCnt; // data to plot amplitude
        HitCntGraph.dataUnit = " Hits    "; // few extra spaces make more space on the left

        HitCntGraph.dataColor = wordCnt; // data to plot colors
        HitCntGraph.dataColorUnit = ""; //we do not need an extra unit for color, so use the empty string

        HitCntGraph.horizontalArray = word; // my indices 

        HitCntGraph.enableMouseMove = 1;
        HitCntGraph.enableMouseDown = 1;
        //HitCntGraph.mouseMoveFunctionAssociated = showData;//triggerMouseMove; shows what data array index are you pointing on
        //HitCntGraph.mouseDownFunctionAssociated = showData;//triggerMouseDown;
        HitCntGraph.enumerateH = 1;
        HitCntGraph.title = "Keywords";
        // optional HitCntGraph.maximum = 255;
        // optional HitCntGraph.maximum = 255;HitCntGraph.minimum = 0.0001;
        HitCntGraph.plot();

    }
}

//get the filename that was selected from php code
var file = document.filex.select.value;

//call the perl script, passing the filename as a parameter
xmlhttp.open(
'GET', 
'dropdown.pl?name=' + encodeURIComponent(file),
false
);

xmlhttp.send();

}
</script>
```

Both the form, a header, and the JS function are in my head section. Then follows the body section which is where I want the graph to be drawn as follows:

```
<body>
<script src="plot_v2.js"></script>
<canvas width="1000" height="300" id="HitCntGraphCanvas" style=""></canvas>
<!-- This div is only needed if mouseMoveFunctionAssociated is used -->
<div id="outputArea"></div>
</body>
```

So, wise ones, This is identical to my older version [before the drop down menu] which worked. I have tested it every step of the way to make sure all components work correct. I came to the very end and like I said, I can even see the CORRECT graph be generated when I press submit...though it only stays up for a second. I would like it to stay on the screen below the drop down menu until the user chooses another file to submit and process. Please help?!

Comment: This isn't a PHP/Apache question so I have removed those tags. This is a front-end JS/HTML concern.

Comment: This is only the second week I have used any of the topics I tagged. I am new to each one, and trying to implement them all. I was not sure how much they all overlapped. Thank you for clarifying -_-, my apologies.

Answer (score 2):

Your JS event handler needs to `return false` (or, you can call `preventDefault()` on the `event` object) to prevent the form from actually submitting back to the page (and causing the page to refresh)

Comment: or... you can change the `<input type="submit" value="Choose File" />` to `<input type="button" value="Choose File" onClick="openfilex()" />`, but then you'd have to send the _filename_ over as a function parameter.

Comment: @DevlshOne Yep, that will work as well. Although I'd still be explicit. You never know when some browser wants to come around and treat the only button in a form as a submit button...

Comment: Agreed... `preventDefault()` has saved my tail numerous times.

Comment: @ColinMorelli, which entity in my code are you referring to when you say JS Event Handler [noob question]. Do you mean to make my openFilex() function return false?

Comment: @DevlshOne your method worked perfectly! Thank you! I would like to make sure and know how to do this for a submit type as well. Everything is a learning experience and prevents more of my really pathetic questions. ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can change the `<input type="submit" value="Choose File" />` to `<input type="button" value="Choose File" onClick="openfilex()" />`, but then you'd have to send the filename over as a function parameter.

Comment: Just so you can come back and recognize what you used as an answer, if you need to later on.